# How to inject one EJB 3.1 into another EJB

Tags: java, jboss, intellij-idea, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I'm developping simple app where one EJB should be injected into another. I'm developping in IDEA Jetbrains IDE. But after i make @EJB annotation in Ejb local statless class my IDE highlight it with error:
EJB '' with component interface 'ApplicationController' not found.

Can anyone tell Why?

Comment: Where did you put the @EJB ? On a class ? Can we see your code ?

Answer (score 14):

Injection of an EJB reference into another EJB can be done using the `@EJB` annotation. Here is an example taken from [Injection of other EJBs Example](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/injection-of-other-ejbs-example.html) from the OpenEJB documentation:

> ### The Code
>
> In this example we develop two simple
>   session stateless beans (DataReader
>   and DataStore), and show how we can
>   use the @EJB annotation in one of
>   these beans to get the reference to
>   the other session bean
>
> #### DataStore session bean
>
> **Bean**
>
> ```
> @Stateless
> public class DataStoreImpl implements DataStoreLocal, DataStoreRemote{
>
>   public String getData() {
>       return "42";
>   }
>
> }
> ```
>
> **Local business interface**
>
> ```
> @Local
> public interface DataStoreLocal {
>
>   public String getData();
>
> }
> ```
>
> **Remote business interface**
>
> ```
> @Remote
> public interface DataStoreRemote {
>
>   public String getData();
>
> }
> ```
>
> #### DataReader session bean
>
> **Bean**
>
> ```
> @Stateless
> public class DataReaderImpl implements DataReaderLocal, DataReaderRemote {
>
>   @EJB private DataStoreRemote dataStoreRemote;
>   @EJB private DataStoreLocal dataStoreLocal;
>
>   public String readDataFromLocalStore() {
>       return "LOCAL:"+dataStoreLocal.getData();
>   }
>
>   public String readDataFromRemoteStore() {
>       return "REMOTE:"+dataStoreRemote.getData();
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Note the usage of the **`@EJB`** annotation
>   on the DataStoreRemote and
>   DataStoreLocal fields. This is the
>   minimum required for EJB ref
>   resolution. If you have two beans that
>   implement the same business
>   interfaces, you'll want to the
>   beanName attribute as follows:
>
> ```
> @EJB(beanName = "DataStoreImpl") 
> private DataStoreRemote dataStoreRemote;
>
> @EJB(beanName = "DataStoreImpl") 
> private DataStoreLocal dataStoreLocal;
> ```
>
> **Local business interface**
>
> ```
> @Local
> public interface DataReaderLocal {
>
>   public String readDataFromLocalStore();
>   public String readDataFromRemoteStore();
> }
> ```
>
> (The remote business interface is not
>   shown for the sake of brevity).

If it doesn't work as expected, maybe show some code.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's an IntelliJ IDEA bug. [This thread](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/288085) solved the problem for me:

> adding a EJB Facet (in project structure > modules) helped

Comment: still happens in IDEA 15. This fix the editor error.